# Programatic output of views block breaks jquery

Tags: views, javascript

I am using the following code to load a views slideshow block:

```
  <?php
            $view       =   'pagetopimage';
            $block_id   =   'block_1';
            $args       =   array(32);
            print views_embed_view( $view, $block_id, $args );
        ?>
```

The block is produced just fine but the javascript that makes the slideshow work is abscent.

**Can you enlighten me about a way to programmatically load the block whilst maintaining the javascript functionality, please?**

Answer (score 1):

I would assume you are just missing the jQuery Cycle plugin.  You might try adding

```
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'views_slideshow') . '/js/jquery.cycle.all.min.js');
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'views_slideshow') . '/contrib/views_slideshow_singleframe/views_slideshow.js');
```

before outputting the view and see if that works.

Comment: I agree with and tried your suggestion but it didn't work. Trying again without loading JS files myself, I get the following error: <br>Drupal.settings.viewsSlideshowSingleFrame is undefined</b>

Comment: @sisko Yep, there seems to be another JS file you need to include for it to work. Edited answer, give that a try